# How to pass data from recycler view to another activity

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

A recycler-view on HomeScreen with values name and city. I want to pass data of recycler-view clicked item to next activity?

database structure is like,

```
- knjdbasgjbascacgjc
    - name: "intex"
    - address: "south avenue"
    - city: "south home"
    - description: "small company"
    - rating: "5"
            
- Khasjdgjacjaghjkhb
    - name: "mmx"
    - address: "north avenue"
    - city: "north home"
    - description: "big company"
    - rating: "3"
```

HomeScreen shows details like:

```
- intex, south avenue, 5
- mmx, north avenue, 3
```

On SecondActivity I want to show details like, on click first item:

```
- intex, south avenue, south home, small company, 5
```

here's my onBindViewHolder,

```
@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final UserViewHolder holder, final int 
    position) {

    BusinessDetailModel businessDetailModel = list.get(position);

    holder.businessName.setText(businessDetailModel.businessName);
    holder.businessCity.setText(businessDetailModel.city);
    holder.businessRating.setText(businessDetailModel.ratingValue + "");

    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {

            Context context = v.getContext();

            intent = new Intent(context, SecondActivity.class);

            context.startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't posted your database structure in your question, and I really do not know how you've stored the age,city and address information.

So, I'll just provide you with a general answer in which I assume that the `datasnapshot` objects retrieved from `childEventListener` contain the above information.

Suppose that the `ChildEventListener` in your `recyclerView` adapter creates POJO objects as follows :-

```
@Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            final YourPOJO pojo = dataSnapshot.getValue(YourPOJO.class);}
```

And it adds it to an `ArrayList<YourPOJO>` object as follows :-

```
list.add(pojo);
notifyItemInserted(list. - 1);
```

Now, in the `onBindViewHolder()` method of your recyclerView adapter, you can call the following to start a new activity and pass it data from your pojo :-

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
holder.yourView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {
                   Intent intent = new 
                   Intent(this,SecondActivty.class);
                   intent.putExtra("age",list.get(position).getAge;
                   intent.putExtra("name",list.get(position).getName;
                   intent.putExtra("address",list.get(position)
                   .getAddress;
                   //and so on for the other values
                   startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Following this, you can just use `getIntent()` in your second activity and obtain the values and display them.

**Edit after viewing onBindViewHolder() code :-**

I want to shed some light on the working of `intents`. Using an `intent`, you can pass data between activities. See my `onBindViewHolder()` code.

So, for your code, just change it to the following :-

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final UserViewHolder holder, final int 
position) {

BusinessDetailModel businessDetailModel = list.get(position);

holder.businessName.setText(businessDetailModel.businessName);
holder.businessCity.setText(businessDetailModel.city);
holder.businessRating.setText(businessDetailModel.ratingValue + "");

holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {

        Context context = v.getContext();

        intent = new Intent(context, BusinessDetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("Name",businessDetailModel.businessName);
        intent.putExtra("City",businessDetailModel.city);
        intent.putExtra("Rating",businessDetailModel.ratingValue);
        //And so on for the rest of the data that you want to pass to 
        //the second activity

        context.startActivity(intent);
    }

});
```

}

After this, in your `BusinessDetailActivity`, you can retrieve the passed data as follows :-

```
String name = getIntent().getExtra("Name");
String city = getIntent().getExtra("City");
//and so on for the rest
```

I would highly recommend you to read up [on intents](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidIntent/article.html).

Comment: Please clarify wether you're using a `ListView` or a `RecyclerView`. Both have different implementations. That'll help me to help you better.

Comment: The code with the `onBindViewHolder` in my answer should work fine for your use case. If you're still having a problem, then post your `onBindViewHolder` code.

Comment: That is because I don't know the view that you are displaying your data in. The `holder.yourView` in my answer is only a generic view that I have used for representation purpose. Similarly, the `SecondActivity.class` in my answer is also for representation purpose only. My code won't work if you just copy and paste it. It's an outline on what to do. You'll obviously have to tailor it to your data.